# How to copy an external java class into generated sources in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

For some reason, I have to copy an external class `ExternalClass.java` into generated sources just like what happens to `BuildConfig.java`.

I want `ExternalClass.java` to be in `build/generated/source/dir/debug`.

I've tried this:

```
task copyExternal(type: Copy) {
  from "path/to/ExternalClass.java"
  to "$buildDir/generated/dir/source/debug"
}
```

But this doesn't work. **How can i copy an external java class into generated sources?**

please don't ask questions like "Why are doing this?" or "Why should you do this?" or the like.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is called `copyExternal` ?

Comment: @ToYonos tried different ways. one was: `preBuild.dependsOn copyExternal`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you just copy and past that java class in your project and rebuild that project, may be this file generated automatically.

Comment: This way we have two `ExternalClass.java` file that can be edited. But it can not be modified when you copy the original one into generated sources. How can i copy it into generated sources using gradle?